# Copiar cada linea de un fichero en archivos de texto diferentes

Tags: c

El ejercicio consiste en leer el contenido de un fichero y copiar cada una de sus lineas en diferentes ficheros o archivos de texto.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fich;
    FILE *fich2;

    char c[500];

    fich=fopen("fichero.txt","r");

    if(fich==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el fichero");
        return 0;
    }

    while(fgets(c,500,fich)){

        printf("%s\n",c);
            fich2=fopen(c,"w");
            fputs(c,fich2);
    }

    fclose(fich);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y? La pregunta?

Comment: Te deseo mucha suerte en tu implementación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema radica en esta parte del código:

```
while(fgets(c,500,fich))
{
    printf("%s\n",c);
    fich2=fopen(c,"w");
    fputs(c,fich2);
}
```

No especificas correctamente la ruta para fopen, además, falta detectar si fopen retorna NULL. Por último, se necesita cerrar el archivo cada vez que abras el fichero, de lo contrario, habrá fuga de memoria (fopen internamente reserva memoria dinámica).

El código quedaría así:

```
while(fgets(c,500,fich))
{
     fich2 = fopen("", "w");
     if(fich2 == NULL)
     {
        //Hay que liberar los recursos del archivo que aún está abierto.
        fclose(fich);
        return 1;
     }
     fputs(c, fich2);
     fclose(fich2);
}
```

Ahora lo que faltaría, es buscar la forma que la ruta vaya cambiando cada vez que se lee una parte del archivo. Es decir, si en mi archivo(fich1) tengo lo siguiente:

- Pepe
- Jose

El nombre pepe lo debemos agregar en un fichero diferente, por ejemplo, en `fichero2.txt`.
Lo mismo pasa con el nombre de jose, hay que añadirlo en un `fichero3.txt` y así sucesivamente.
Para lograr completar este algoritmo, necesitamos apoyarnos de una variable acumuladora y de la función `sprintf`, de ese modo, podemos formatear la cadena en tiempo de ejecución y crear la ruta apropiada para crear el fichero.

El código completo quedaría así:

```
int main(void)
{
    int id = 0;
    char result[16];
    FILE *fich, *fich2;
    char c[500];
    fich = fopen("fichero.txt", "r");

    if(fich == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el fichero");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(c,500,fich))
    {
        printf("%s", c);
        ++id;
        sprintf(result, "fichero%d.txt", id+1);
        fich2 = fopen(result, "w");
        if(fich2 == NULL)
        {
            fclose(fich);
            return 1;
        }
        fputs(c, fich2);
        fclose(fich2);
    }
    fclose(fich);
    return 0;
}
```